# Is there any way to catch an exception from the service in NestJS using an exception filter

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have created the exception filter and registered it globally but when I throw a HTTP exception from the service file the exception filter does not catch the exception but while throwing the exception from the controller exception filter catches the exception properly.

The exception filter:

```js
import {
  ArgumentsHost,
  Catch,
  ExceptionFilter,
  HttpException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class CommonFilter<T extends HttpException> implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: T, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('getting in common filter');
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
    });
  }
}
```

Registered as global:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommonFilter } from './common/common.filter';
import {
  MongooseExeptions,
  MongooseValidationError,
} from './common/mongoose.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
  app.useGlobalFilters(
    new CommonFilter(),
    new MongooseExeptions(),
    new MongooseValidationError(),
  );

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

The service function:

```js
try {
  const pwdHash = hash(createUserDto.password, 5);
  const storeUser = await this.usersSchema.create({
    ...createUserDto,
    password: pwdHash,
  });
  if (storeUser) {
    const genrateOtp = new OTPGenrator().genrate(4);
    await this.UserOtpMailer.UserOtpMailer(
      storeUser.email,
      storeUser.name,
      genrateOtp,
    );
    return storeUser;
  }
  return;
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof Error.ValidationError) {
    throw new HttpException(
      error.message,
      HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    );
  } else {
    throw new HttpException(
      error.message,
      HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    );
  }
}
```

This service will throw the mongoose validation error as `pwdHash` is not type of string and I am throwing HTTP exception if it is validation error.

But if I throw the same error form the controller it will work fine but from service exceptions are not getting caught.

Answer (score 2):

I had a mistake in my code and because of that controller was not able to catch the exception. I just needed to put `await` from the controller to service function.

So we don't need to make any special setup for the nest to catch exception from the service file.

Comment: Hey there! Could you please share an example of how you wired that up?

Comment: hi as i mentioned i forgot to use await for that particular service method what you are up to?

Comment: Same error... Googled a lot

Answer (score 0):

The exception filter will only catch errors if they are thrown within the context of a request handled by a controller. This is because the exception filter is registered at the application level.

in controller do this:

```
async functionName() {
   try{
      ...
   } catch (error) {
      throw error;
   }
}
```

or use `@UseFilter(exceptionFilter)` in your controller to handle exceptions thrown by services, and register it at the controller

```
@Controller()
@UseFilters(MyExceptionFilter)
export class MyController {
   ...
}
```

with

```
@Injectable()
export class MyExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();

    if (exception instanceof HttpException) {
      response.status(exception.getStatus()).json({
        statusCode: exception.getStatus(),
        message: exception.message,
      });
    } else {
      response.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
        statusCode: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        message: 'Internal server error',
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is already the same as my filters are registered globally and exception is throwing in the service file and service is used by controller so this should not make any difference but still i tried it again but the results are same

Comment: thanks, @AhmadDeel for the reply logically your answer is correct 100% but there was an issue in my code.